# vba Word how to get sentences in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word, sentence

I have a Word document, with the first two sentences as normal text and sentences three and four in a table (in one cell):

```
My first sentence. My second sentence.

My third sentence. My fourth sentence.
```

My code is the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim sentence As Variant
    Dim i As Long: i = 0
    
    Selection.Expand wdSentence
    Debug.Print "--------->" & ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Sentences.Count
    Debug.Print "selection: " & ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection
    For Each sentence In ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Sentences
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print i & " sentence: " & sentence
    Next

End Sub
```

If I select the first two sentences, the debug output is correct:

```
--------->2
selection: My first sentence. My second sentence.


1 sentence: My first sentence. 
2 sentence: My second sentence.
```

If I select the two sentences in the table, the debug output is strange (or wrong?):

```
--------->2
selection: My third sentence. My fourth sentence.

1 sentence: My third sentence.
```

Why is the output of the table content different from normal text? How can I get the same result for the table content as for the normal text?

Comment: The fundamental problem is that VBA has no idea what a grammatical sentence is. For example, consider the following: "Mr. Smith spent $1,234.56 at Dr. John's Grocery Store, to buy: 10.25kg of potatoes; 10kg of avocados; and 15.1kg of Mrs. Green's Mt. Pleasant macadamia nuts." For you and me, that would count as one sentence; for VBA it counts as 5 sentences.

Comment: Absolutely correct! That's why I corrected that in my macro. 
In this case, however, part of the selection is not displayed. A piece of text is simply left out. It could be a VBA bug. I also checked it with n x m tables. VBA has problems with more than one sentence in a cell. In such case, Sentence.Information (wdWithInTable) indicates that the 2nd sentence is not contained in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables bring a another whole dimension of complexity to what Word recognizes as a sentence. Paragraph, end of cell marks, and end of row markers all factor into the confusion of what constitutes a sentence to VBA.

Here is some code that should work, but I can’t claim with 100% certainty that it will work in all situations. In other words, I know it can be improved upon, but it should give you a good start for your own debugging sessions.

```
Sub ParseBySentence()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim i As Long, s As Long, para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim rng As Word.Range, sRng As Word.Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To doc.Paragraphs.Count
        Set para = doc.Paragraphs(i)
        If para.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Set rng = para.Range
            Do While Asc(rng.Characters.Last) = 13
                rng.MoveEnd unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
            Loop
            If rng.Text = vbNullString Or _
                Asc(rng.Text) = 13 Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                For s = 1 To rng.Sentences.Count
                    Set sRng = rng.Sentences(s)
                    Do While Asc(sRng.Characters.Last) = 13
                        sRng.MoveEnd unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
                    Loop
                    sRng.Select
                    Debug.Print Selection.Text
                    Selection.Collapse Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Action Complete"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@Rich Michaels: Thanks for the hint with the paragraphs. I made a fast and minimalistic macro that also works in tables:

```
Sub Par2Sen()
    Dim s0, s1, smax As Long
    Dim para As Word.Paragraph
    Dim r() As Byte

    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        r = para.Range
        Debug.Print "> Paragraph= " & para.Range;
        smax = UBound(r) - 1
        s0 = 0
        s1 = 0
        Do Until s1 > smax
            If r(s1) = 46 Or s1 = smax Then
                Debug.Print "-> Sen from" & (s0 / 2) + 1 & " to " & (s1 / 2) + 1 & MidB$(r, s0 + 1, s1 - s0 + 3)
                s0 = s1 + 2
            End If
            s1 = s1 + 2
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```